# The PyQt5 custom widget opens in another window

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a "Planet" class in which each object is drawn according to the specified parameters as a separate widget. I also created the "SolarSystem" class, which creates a list of "Planet" objects. Then I try to display all the list items in the "SolarSystem" window, but for some reason, instead of all the drawings being displayed in one window, each opens in a new one. What am I doing wrong?

class Planet

```
from PyQt5 import  QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from SolarSystem import SolarSystem
from Planet import Planet

class Planet(QtWidgets.QWidget):
def __init__(self, name: str, object_diameter: int, orbit_radius: float, speed_degrees_earth_day: float, color, \*args, \*\*kwargs):
super().__init__(\*args, \*\*kwargs)
self.color = color
self.object_diameter = object_diameter
self.name = name
self.orbit_radius = orbit_radius
self.speed_degrees_earth_day = speed_degrees_earth_day
self.setSizePolicy(
QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding,
QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.MinimumExpanding
)
self.current_x = orbit_radius
self.current_y = orbit_radius

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        super().paintEvent(e)
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(self.color, 8, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(self.color, Qt.SolidPattern))
        painter.drawEllipse(QPoint(self.current_x, self.current_y),
                            self.object_diameter,
                            self.object_diameter
                            )
    
        painter.end()
```

class SolarSystem

```
class SolarSystem(QtWidgets.QWidget):
space_objects: list\[Planet\]

    def __init__(self, space_objects: list[list], *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.space_objects = []
        for planet in space_objects:
            new_space_objects = Planet(*planet)
            self.space_objects.append(new_space_objects)
        self.initUi()
        self.show()
    
    def initUi(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 700)
        for i in self.space_objects:
            self.p = i
            self.p.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000)
            self.p.show()
```

class MainWindow

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
def __init__(self):
super().__init__()

        planets_list = [
            ['Sun', 50, 10, 0, Qt.yellow],
            ['Mercury', 50, 20, 0, Qt.darkYellow],
            ['Venus', 50, 30, 0, Qt.yellow],
            ['Earth', 50, 40, 0, Qt.blue],
            ['Mars', 50, 50, 0, Qt.red],
            ['Jupiter', 50, 60, 0, Qt.darkRed],
            ['Saturn', 50, 70, 0, Qt.darkYellow],
            ['Uranus', 50, 80, 0, Qt.darkGreen],
            ['Neptune', 50, 90, 0, Qt.darkBlue]
        ]
        self.solar_system = SolarSystem(planets_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
app = QApplication(\[\])
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

I want all created objects of the "Planet" class to be displayed on the Solar System window. I don't want to use Layout to move these objects in the future.

Comment: You'll have to set the Solarsystem as a parent of the Planet widgets. But with your current code they will all be on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the planets as child widgets of the `SolarSystem` widget, the way to do this is to pass self (`SolarSystem` instance) as the parent for each `Planet` instance, also remove the `self.p.show()` as it is not needed.

```
class SolarSystem(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    space_objects: list[Planet]

    def __init__(self, space_objects: list[list], *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.space_objects = []
        for planet in space_objects:
            new_space_object = Planet(*planet, self)  # Pass 'self' as the parent
            self.space_objects.append(new_space_object)
        self.initUi()
        self.show()

    def initUi(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 800, 700)
        for i in self.space_objects:
            self.p = i
            self.p.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 1000)
            # self.p.show()  # Remove this line
```